# WooCommerce Default Pages NOT showing up on brand new site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I recently installed WooCommerce on a brand new Wordpress website. I went through all the steps as directed exactly in this tutorial I found on YouTube [How To Create An eCommerce Website With Wordpress 2021 -ONLINE STORE- (Easy For Beginners)](https://youtu.be/TDNGEFd-aEE)

I then needed to edit the cart, shop, account, etc. pages. The only problem I have is that those pages did not generate when I installed WooCommerce. They do not exist. I have tried multiple ways to solve my problem. One of which is a tool that WooCommerce has in their plugin. If I go to WooCommerce-->Status-->Tools and scroll down I have an option that says, "**Create default WooCommerce pages**
Note: This tool will install all the missing WooCommerce pages. Pages already defined and set up will not be replaced."

This option DOES NOT install missing WooCommerce pages.

WooCommerce-->Settings-->Advanced No Default Pages:

[image]

Appearance-->Menus-->View All No Default Pages:

[image]

How can I fix this so that I can create the needed default pages and continue creating my online store?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of solving this issue. But following the guideline on woocommerce website, please try manual instructions below.

First make sure there no default pages, Cart, Checkout and My Account page exists, Not as publish or draft or event in trash.

Then go ahead and create new pages for each as mentioned below.

- Create a cart page and paste the shortcode [woocommerce_cart]
- Create checkout page and paste the shortcode [woocommerce_checkout]
- Create My Account page and paste shortcode [woocommerce_my_account]

This should do the trick, Also make sure that in permalinks options available under Settings -> Permalinks and make sure Post Name is selected and click save changes.

If this does not work for you, do post a comment with exact screenshot of the issue.

Article link on official website - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-pages/

Comment: I am not familiar with where to put the shortcode for each of the new pages. I think WordPress has been updated since the documentation I was able to find because it did not look like my version of WordPress so I couldn't find where to put it.

Also, if I get the pages to work correctly they will be blank pages. WooCommerce has the default pages already with sample content and all the correct/needed info for each page. Is there a way to get those WooCommerce templates for each page?

Comment: can you post the link to the page or website that you are working on so it can be better understood. If you have the shortcode on the page, then it should work. Irrelevant of what wordpress version you use, all you do is add a new text block and add shortcode there or use classic editor plugin to use previous version layout. If you are using any plugin, deactivate it to check if there is any plugin conflict (woocommerce can sometimes act oddly with other plugins)

Comment: Here is a link to quick video explaining how to achieve this - https://youtu.be/Ce3sH1vXO3w